# PHP/MySQLi - looping through an array to build dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I've been stuck on something for a couple of days now and I'm really hoping someone can help me please.

I have an array called $default_districts which generated by a query to find the postcode districts within a predefined radius from a point... so the number of values stored is dynamic.

```
[0] => NR1
[1] => NR12
[2] => NR13
[3] => NR14
... etc.
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to find out how many customers are within a "radius" from another address.
So, I want to use those values binded to a prepared statement...

e.g.

```
// get data records within the default radius
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT clientdata_urn, clientdata_district
FROM tblhub_clientdata
WHERE clientdata_district = ?)) {

// bind param to vars
$stmt->bind_param( // LOOP THROUGH $default_districts HERE // ));

// execute statement
$stmt->execute();

// store
$stmt->store_result();

// get numrows
$total_numrows = $stmt->num_rows;

// close statement
$stmt->close();

} else {

// error
printf("Error counting total data within default radius: %s\n", $mysqli->error);

}
```

If I hardcode what I'm trying to create it would be something like this...

```
SELECT clientdata_urn, clientdata_district
FROM tblhub_clientdata
WHERE clientdata_district = 'NR1' OR clientdata_district = 'NR12' OR clientdata_district = 'NR13' OR clientdata_district = 'NR14'
```

I'm a bit of a newbie and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You want number of values not the values?If yes then better to use **GROUP BY** with **HAVING** . In **GROUP BY** we use **HAVING** in place of **WHERE** mysql statement. Following links may help you.   http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Rather than using lots of OR statements for possible values of the same field, you'd be better looking IN an array: WHERE x IN ('a','b','c')

Comment: Thanks @web2students but my problem is selecting records where 'clientdata_district' matches any of the values in my array - which neither of those links mention, so not sure how changing to GROUP BY will address that?

Comment: Thanks @Eddy. I've tried that route but without success. Are you able to provide an example please.

Comment: @Rachi Any sql tutorial site will cover this, but as you requested an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: @Eddy Thank you but that link doesn't mention prepared statements. I'm trying to loop values out of an array and bind them to a prepared statement.

Comment: Here is example  - `**SELECT *,count(*) FROM table_name group by column HAVING  column = 'NR1' or column = 'NR2' **`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, @Rachi. I believe this will solve your problem.

First, you're a lot better off using IN rather than a series of OR statements. I put together an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9639/3/0) to demonstrate this.

This takes the form

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as num_users, clientdata_district
FROM tblhub_clientdata
WHERE clientdata_district IN ('NR12', 'NR14')
GROUP BY clientdata_district
```

The output gives you the number of users within each of the area codes in the array. If you want the total number of users in ALL areas within your area (your question wasn't clear) then simply remove the GROUP BY line [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9639/4/0).

The next challenge is to build your string so that you can put it into the query. The easiest way to do this is with the [implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$query_string = implode(",", $default_districts)
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as num_users, clientdata_district";
$sql.= "FROM tblhub_clientdata";
$sql.= "WHERE clientdata_district IN ($query_string)";
$sql.= "GROUP BY clientdata_district";
```

NOTE that this will not add ' marks to your area codes, but from what I've seen of your codes I don't think that will matter. Worst case just throw away the implode statement and build the string in a FOR loop.